# How to Make Generic Precision ISO Timestamp Generator

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I am writing a utility function that returns the current time in ISO format. However, I would like to be able to specify the precision:

```
2017-04-28T15:07:37Z        //s
2017-04-28T15:07:37.035Z    //ms
2017-04-28T15:07:37.035332Z //us
```

I have working code to do this, however, I can't seem to find a way to make it generic:

```
string getISOCurrentTimestamp_us()
{
    char iso_buf[30];

    auto now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto s = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
    time_t seconds = (time_t) s.count();
    strftime(iso_buf, sizeof(iso_buf), "%FT%T", gmtime(&seconds));

    string iso_timestamp(iso_buf);

    auto us = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
    auto us_diff = us - chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(s);
    char buffer[8];
    std::snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ".%06d", (int) us_diff.count());

    iso_timestamp += string(buffer);
    iso_timestamp += "Z";

    return iso_timestamp;
}
```

As you can see, this one only returns the microsecond version. I have a separate function using `chrono:milliseconds` for the millisecond version. Seems like a DRY violation to have so much similar code when the only difference is the duration template parameter and the zero-padding.

Yet being able to specify the duration is tricky. I think I'm not quite understanding function templates, because I tried something like `getISOCurrentTimestamp<chrono::microseconds>()`, to no avail:

```
template <class T>
string getISOCurrentTimestamp() {
    ...
    auto t = chrono::duration_cast<T>(now.time_since_epoch());
    auto t_diff = t - chrono::duration_cast<T>(s);
}
```

Another problem is deducing the amount of zero padding based on `T` which doesn't seem trivial either (i.e. microseconds should be zero-padded up to 6, milliseconds up to 3, etc.

How can I make this ISO String function generic? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Edit: Using @HowardHinnant's library, I was able to write a generic wrapper:

```
template <class Precision>
string getISOCurrentTimestamp()
{
    auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();
    return date::format("%FT%TZ", date::floor<Precision>(now));
}
```

Invoked using:

`string timestamp = getISOCurrentTimestamp<chrono::seconds>()`

Comment: Just take the output with the highest precision and trunkate it.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "to no avail"? Was there a compiler error, and if so what was it? Was the output wrong, and if so what did it look like and how should it have looked?

Comment: You _should_ _not_ use `high_resolution_clock` for this.  Only `system_clock`.  The epoch of `high_resolution_clock` varies from platform to platform.

Comment: Now your `getISOCurrentTimestamp()` works with [`microfortnights`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#microfortnights). ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [free, open-source, header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) does this by adjusting the precision of the `chrono::time_point` that is input into the `format` function.  Feel free to inspect the code to see how this is done.  I think you'll be especially interested in [`decimal_format_seconds`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h#L3468) which is responsible for computing how many fractional decimal digits to output (if any).  Or feel free to just use this code.

Here is what using it looks like:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    system_clock::time_point now = sys_days{2017_y/04/28} + 15h + 7min + 37s + 35332us;
    cout << format("%FT%TZ\n", floor<seconds>(now));
    cout << format("%FT%TZ\n", floor<milliseconds>(now));
    cout << format("%FT%TZ\n", floor<microseconds>(now));
}
```

with the output:

```
2017-04-28T15:07:37Z
2017-04-28T15:07:37.035Z
2017-04-28T15:07:37.035332Z
```

Comment: That's a fancy library, where did you find it? ;-)

Comment: I'm working on have _you_ finding it in `<chrono>` in the future. ;-)

Comment: I actually ran across this library earlier, but somehow I missed that you could easily format timestamp strings with it - I'll try it out!

Comment: This library is great. I was able to make a simple wrapper around your `format` function to achieve what I wanted.